# Phalcon\Mvc\Model serialization - object properties are lost

Tags: php, phalcon

Serializing Phalcon\Mvc\Model loses object property that's not a part of schema.

I have the following Model, which upon load sets array of states:

```
class Country extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    protected $states;

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSource('countries');
    }

    public function afterFetch()
    {
        if ($this->id) {
            $this->states = ['AL', 'AZ', 'NV', 'NY'];
        }
    }
}
```

I do this:

```
    $country = Country::findFirst($countryId);
    $serialized = serialize($country);
    $unserialized = unserialize($serialized);
```

*$serialized* string does not even contain "states" substring. Hence, "states" are missing in unserialized object.

I have discovered this while working on user authentication and persistence in session (which involved serialization/unserialization). My User object was losing all properties that were loaded in afterFetch() phase.

Two questions:

1. Why did "states" property disappear upon serialization?
2. Is it a bad practice in Phalcon world to persist models (which I thought is a convenient way of storing user object in session)?

I am on Phalcon 1.3.0.

Thanks,
Temuri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\Phalcon\Mvc\Model implements Serializable interface.

To serialize your own properties (which \Phalcon\Mvc\Model is unaware of), you will need to use a trick like this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php#107194

```
public function serialize()
{
    $data = array(
        'states' => $this->states,
        'parent' => parent::serialize(),
    );

    return serialize($data);
}

public function unserialize($str)
{
    $data = unserialize($str);
    parent::unserialize($data['parent']);
    unset($data['parent']);
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Github user alanbarber111 has posted an interesting snippet: github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/1285

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - Phalcon serializer currently ignores all non-Model properties in order to make serialized objects light.

I've filed a new NFR: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/1285.